# Use the name of a shape as an identifier in a form

Tags: vba, cell, shapes, paste

I'm creating a booking worksheet using shapes and an Excel form.

```vb
Sub MyShape_Click()
Dim sh As Shape
Set sh = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller)

sh.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 255)

If MsgBox("This will confirm the reservation! Are you sure?", vbYesNo, "Reservation") = vbNo Then Exit Sub

sh.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
CallingShapeName = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).Name

MsgBox CallingShapeName
Call Reservations

End Sub


Sub Reservations()

If ActiveSheet.Name = "Reservations" Then
    Sheets("Form").Activate
Else
    Sheets("Reservation").Activate
End If
Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select

'Show the default data entry form
ActiveSheet.ShowDataForm

End Sub
```

How do I paste the name of the shape into the cell in Reservations?